# Auto Layout and setting constraints is changing the sizes of the buttons in my app

Tags: ios, button, autolayout, resize, constraints

I'm trying to resize my app by using constraints and auto layout so that it can fix on every iPhone screen, the only problem I'm having is that the size of the buttons in my app are getting smaller as i move to the 4 inch and 3.5 inch. Im working in inferred view, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: share scrrenshot and constraint details

Comment: How 's your code or xib?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints instead of using height and width. If problem persists share the screenshots along with the constraints.